# Excel Ignoring If Statement During Index/Match/If/Large Command

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, match, multiple-select

I'm trying to create a chart that finds the name of the first (then second, third, fourth, etc.) largest entry (via total sales) that meet certain criteria from a second Excel worksheet. (i.e. I want to find the largest sales value that is of the good "Apples" and sold in "Europe" if you will, as well as display the customer that this largest sales dollar amount was sold to.)

I've created some code that is giving me the name corresponding to the largest value on the sheet (very good!). However, this name does not meet the criteria in my if statement.

Example code: `=INDEX('Sheet1'!B:B,MATCH(1,INDEX(('Sheet1'!V:V=LARGE(IF(AND('2. Sheet1'!E2:E1000="Apple", 'Sheet1'!W2:W1000="Europe"), 'Sheet1'!V:V, ""), ROWS(C$1:C1)))*(COUNTIF(C$1:C1,'Sheet1'!B:B)=0),),0))`

B is the column with the customer name, V is the column with the overall sales amount, E is the column showing the name of the item sold, W is the name of the geographic area, C is the column (on the new sheet) where the name of the customer will be duplicated.

What I want to see is the customer who bought the most apples in Europe...but instead I'm getting the largest sales volume over all.

To make it stranger, if "apples" and "Europe" don't appear on the top row of Sheet1, I'm getting #N/A. (This does not happen, though, if these are contained in the top row.)

Does anyone have any thoughts as to how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following sample data image, the formulas in AB2:AC2 are:

```
=AGGREGATE(14, 6, (V$2:V$21)/((W$2:W$21=AA2)*(E$2:E$21=Z2)), COUNTIFS(Z$2:Z2, Z2, AA$2:AA2, AA2))
=INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($2:$21)/((E$2:E$21=Z2)*(W$2:W$21=AA2)*(V$2:V$21=AB2)), COUNTIFS(Z$2:Z2, Z2, AA$2:AA2, AA2, AB$2:AB2, AB2)))
```

If you need to do it all in one formula, substitute the formula from AB2 (*sans =*) for every occurrence of AB2 within the formula from AC2.

Fill down as necessary.

[image]

Comment: Yay, it is working! Thank you so much for all of your help! (I ended up not combining it as it was easier to troubleshoot by setting up hidden columns to run the calculations, but so happy that I got this to work. Thank you again!)